# How to use JSONLibrary in Android Studio after adding to the Library

Tags: android, android-studio

I have to use `JSONObject.getNames` I downloaded `org.json` jar and added to library of android studio but it is not working but when the same is added to netbeans it is working ! Android studio is recognising.Totally frustrated.Lost half a day in this.

[image]

```
static JSONObject convert(JSONObject initial) {
        Map<String, Map<String, List<Map<String, Object>>>> stateToCityToAddresses = new HashMap<>();

        String[] codes = JSONObject.getNames(initial);//getNames not recognisable

        for (String code : codes) {


            JSONObject state = initial.getJSONObject(code);




            String stateName = state.getString("STATE");
            String cityName = state.getString("CITY");
            String ifsc = state.getString("IFSC");
            String contact = state.getString("BRANCH");


            List<Map<String, Object>> addresses = stateToCityToAddresses
                .computeIfAbsent(stateName, sn -> new HashMap<>()) 
                .computeIfAbsent(cityName, cn -> new ArrayList<>()); 

            Map<String, Object> address = new HashMap<>();
            address.put("ID", ifsc);
            address.put("BRANCH", contact);
            address.put("CODE", code);
            addresses.add(address);
        }

        JSONObject result = new JSONObject(stateToCityToAddresses);



        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Show the detail code about it. And do you want to get the key of `json` ?

Comment: @manobromno use gson instead of JSON. it's far more superior than this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple method to get the keys for the time being.

```
public String[] getKeysFromJSONObject(JSONObject obj){
   List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
   Iterator<String> iter = obj.keys(); //This should be the iterator you want.
   while(iter.hasNext()){
       keys.add(iter.next());
   return keys.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```